# dask : How to read CSV files into a DataFrame from Microsoft Azure Blob

Tags: python, pandas, azure, android-asynctask, dask

S3Fs is a Pythonic file interface to S3, **does DASK have any Pythonic interface to Azure Storage Blob**. Python SDK's for Azure Storage Blob provide ways to read and write to blob, but the interface requires the file to be downloaded to the local machine from cloud. I am looking for solutions that which read the blob to support DASK parallel read as either stream or string **without persisting to local disk**.

Comment: Might azure-datalake storage be a solution for you?

Comment: Its an option, could you point me to solutions implemented using azure-data lake.

Answer (score 1):

I have newly pushed code here: https://github.com/dask/dask-adlfs

You may pip-install from that location, although you may be best served by conda-installing the requirements (dask, cffi, oauthlib) beforehand. In a python session, doing `import dask_adlfs` will be enough to register the backend with Dask, such that thereafter you can use azure URLs with dask functions like:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('adl://mystore/path/to/*.csv', storage_options={
    tenant_id='mytenant', client_id='myclient', 
    client_secret='mysecret'})
```

Since this code is totally brand new and untested, expect rough edges. With luck, you can help iron out those edges.